# how to write an if statement that receives a string but requires two values to unpack python

Tags: python

```
print("Sample commands: insert 25, select 1")
coinsaccepted = (50,25,10,5)
selectlist = (1,2,3,4,5)
x = input("Your command : ")
command, value = x.split(' ')
value = int(value)
if x == "quit":
            return False
elif value in coinsaccepted:
            return True
```

So for the console it prints out a command, and usually the command is insert 25, or select 1, or insert 35, etc.

I needed the value that they put in, like for insert 25, i needed 25.

However, I also need an if statement that if it equals just the word "quit" or even "cancel" that it stops the program.

The if statement is correct, however, I get the error that

```
value = x.split(' ')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

So the problem is that quit is only one value. What can I do?

Comment: How about checking the input for a space before attempting to split it?

Comment: so writing an if statement like this: ``` If x = '  ' pass ```

Answer (score 0):

You should check for **x** first before you split it.

```
print("Sample commands: insert 25, select 1")
coinsaccepted = (50, 25, 10, 5)
selectlist = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
x = input("Your command : ")
if x == "quit":
    return False
else:
    command, value = x.split(" ")
    if value in coinsaccepted:
        return True
```

Comment: whoa, you just blew my mind. You can have an if statement inside of an else?? Also, could you have elifs in else? How do you end it? Like after the if statements inside of the else, do you write another else?

Comment: Yes you can have nested if-statements but it will slow down your program. The above code can be simplified further but for you to understand the code i did not simplify it.

Comment: okay, so in the else statement, after the if statements, do i have to do another else?

Comment: what do you mean "do another else"?